# What does the "second coming of Christ" mean?

Tags: terminology, second-coming, antichrist

I am not up on my scripture but is the 'second coming of Christ', Jesus specifically?

'Christ' is a title, meaning the 'anointed one', so is the 'second coming' Jesus coming down from a cloud, or is it the coming of a yet another 'anointed one'?

Comment: I don't think this is a verse search question, but more of a terminology question. In that regard it's rather basic, and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Coming) explains it quite well.

Comment: _Art thou he that should come, or do we look for another?_ Matthew 11:3.

Comment: Like a Superman perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually many Christians are confused about the 2nd Coming and what it means, particularly as to how it fits with lots of other end times events - such as the Antichrist, the Mark of the Beast, 2 Witnesses, 3rd Temple and other events.
One example of this is that it's very common in many denominations to hear people talk about or make a reference to Jesus' coming, but they really mean the rapture.

*At the rapture, Christ comes FOR his bride- [the Christians] but he doesn't come down to earth. We are caught.up quickly into the clouds- just as the bride in a Hebrew wedding is literally lifted up and carried away.

Let's break it down a bit in a way that will clarify.

It's helpful to explain it in terms of Christ's first Advent and Christ's Second Advent.

- The First Advent is Christ's birth, life, ministry, miracles, death, burial and resurrection.  Many events, - all part of his first advent or first coming to earth as a **baby/ suffering servant**. Advent means "arrival" or "coming".
- In the same way, we are looking for Christ's second Advent.  This also is many events, but all connected or linked to Christ's second coming to earth as a j**udge/ conquering king.**
  It includes the rapture [which is from the Latin word "rapturo" and literally means to be caught up, snatched up quickly by force], when Christians who have died will be resurrected, and those Christians who are alive [us] will be caught up/raptured into the clouds as the bride. It also includes the events of Revelation, the Anti-Christ, the Mark of the Beast, the bowl judgments poured out, the two witnesses who are killed and resurrected, the great white throne judgement, Christ returning to earth with his bride, and the 1000 year millennial reign of Christ.

This is the predominant view held by most Protestant denominations, but there is a lot of differing views on the timing of the rapture, in relation the 7 year tribulation. [Whether the rapture happens before the Tribulation starts, in the middle, at the end, or in the 2nd half, but before God's wrath is poured out.] This is where the terms Pre-Tribulation, Mid-Tribulation, Post-tribulation, and Pre-wrath come from. They are all referring to the timing of the rapture in relation to the Tribulation.
**The important thing to keep in mind is that the Rapture and 2nd coming are two very separate and distinct events with totally different goals and purposes.**

The Second coming is the "**Day of the Lord**" and it is used by Paul and OT writers. It is always linked with gloom, calamity, judgment and darkness. Sun turns black and the moon turns to blood. This is Christ coming back to earth with his bride. “[The Day of the Lord](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_of_the_Lord#:%7E:text=%22The%20Day%20of%20the%20Lord,in%20Acts%202%3A20)" is a biblical term and theme used in both the Hebrew Bible (יֹום יְהוָה) and the New Testament (ἡμέρα κυρίου), as in "The sun shall be turned into darkness, and the moon into blood, before the great and the terrible day of the LORD come" (Joel 2:31, cited in Acts 2:20).

In stark contrast is the Rapture - which is the Day of Christ. The Greek word in the New Testament is Harpazo. This is a wedding celebration, and Christ comes FOR his bride, and we meet him in the clouds.

The two most well-known passages about the rapture are  1 **Thessallonians 4:14-18 and 1 Corinthians 15:51,52.**

It's interesting and very significant that both these passages were written to two early church congregations of mixed Jewish and Gentile believers, and written by the same author - Paul.

Here is an excellent article, and it explains why the "Last Trumpet" used by Paul to tell us when the rapture happens is categorically not the 7th Trumpet in Revelations. [Rapture at the Seventh Trumpet Judgment?](https://www.versebyverseministry.org/bible-answers/which-trumpet-announces-the-rapture)

Answer (score 2):

Read Matthew 24:30(ESV) - "Then will appear in heaven the sign of the Son of Man, and then all the tribes of the earth will mourn, and they will see the Son of Man coming on the clouds of heaven with power and great glory..."

Jesus referred to himself as, and is referred to as, the "Son of Man" many times throughout the New Testament.  In fact the New Testament in general refers to the return of the "Son of Man", rather than the return of Christ.
Also ref. Matthew 24:36-39.

In Revelation 20:4-6, "Christ" is used not as a title but as a proper noun.  While the word Christ is a title, it has now become the name of our savior and is his alone, the name above every name (Philippians 2:9-11).

There is only one savior, one Messiah, which is our Lord Jesus Christ, the true Son of God, and the Son of Man.

Jesus warns us not to believe the false Messiahs who will appear (Matthew 24:23-27).

It is definitely Jesus Christ himself who will return to gather his elect.  I pray to the Lord that you and I will be among them.

Answer (score 2):

Without getting into an elaborate explanation about the second coming of Christ, I'll say simply that you could just as accurately have called the "second coming of Christ" the second coming of our **Lord Jesus Christ**.

> Concerning the coming of our ***Lord Jesus Christ*** and our being gathered to him, we ask you, brothers and sisters,  not to become easily unsettled or alarmed by the teaching allegedly from us—whether by a prophecy or by word of mouth or by letter—asserting that the day of the Lord has already come (2 Thessalonians 2:1-2 NIV, my emphasis).

Jesus's *first* coming began with his conception by the Holy Spirit in the womb of the virgin Mary. His *second* coming will occur--according to the Father's good timing--when he appears in the clouds, above the earth.

> For the Lord himself will come down from heaven, with a loud command, with the voice of the archangel and with the trumpet call of God, and the dead in Christ will rise first. After that, we who are still alive and are left will be caught up together with them in the clouds to meet the Lord in the air. And so we will be with the Lord forever. Therefore encourage one another with these words (1 Thessalonians 4:16-18 NIV).

(As for Christ's *third* [advent](https://dailyverse.knowing-jesus.com/zechariah-14-4), it will occur

> at the end of . . . [a] time
> of terrible judgment--sometimes referred to as 'the great and
> terrible day of the Lord' and elsewhere called, 'the time of Jacob's
> trouble'. Zechariah gives a clear description of certain end-time
> events and like many Old Testament prophets gives clear insight into
> God's unfolding plan of redemption.)

Yes, the word *Christ* means "anointed one." In light of Jesus's second coming, consider the word Christ as an honorific stressing his kingly identity. Just as the Hebrew kings of old were anointed, as was King David by Samuel (see 1 Samuel 16), Jesus was anointed by his Father to be the king over all kings and the Lord over all lords (1 Timothy 6:15; Revelation 17:14; and Revelation 19:16). Jesus's anointing took place in the counsels of God in eternity past.

During his earthly ministry, Jesus recognized and bore witness to the truth that he was God's Anointed One when in the synagogue in Nazareth he read from the prophet Isaiah:

> He went to Nazareth, where he had been brought up, and on the Sabbath day he went into the synagogue, as was his custom. He stood up
> to read, and the scroll of the prophet Isaiah was handed to him.
> Unrolling it, he found the place where it is written:
>
> ```
> “The Spirit of the Lord is on me,
> because he has anointed me
> to proclaim good news to the poor.
>   He has sent me to proclaim freedom for the prisoners
> and recovery of sight for the blind,
>   to set the oppressed free,
> to proclaim the year of the Lord’s favor.”
> ```
>
> Then he rolled up the scroll, gave it back to the attendant and sat
> down. The eyes of everyone in the synagogue were fastened on him. He
> began by saying to them, “Today this scripture is fulfilled in your
> hearing” (Luke 4:16-21 NIV).

Notice in verse 18 of Luke 4 that Jesus told his audience in the synagogue that his anointing (really, his second anointing) was being fulfilled in their presence.

Jesus was anointed by his Father in eternity; he announced and then lived in the Spirit of that anointing during his public ministry.

As for "false Messiahs," well, I guess you could call them with some accuracy  *antichrists* (see 1 John 2:18).

Comment: But you didn't really answer his question of what the 2nd coming is at all.

Comment: Wasnt Jesus anointed by the Holy Spirit on the mountain of transfiguration?

Comment: @AndreChaisson At Jesus' baptism the Holy Spirit descended upon Jesus in bodily form, like a dove. That is not to say he was not already anointed. But that demonstration is an outward signification of the reality.

Comment: @Tennman7: I've edited my answer in response to your comment.

Comment: @AndreChaisson: What Nigel said, plus . . ..No, not specifically. I'm not saying the Holy Spirit had nothing to do with Jesus's Transfiguration. I'm sure he did. There is at least one other instance in the life of Jesus that could possibly be termed an "anointing," although the text does not specifically call it that: "When all the people were being baptized, Jesus was baptized too. And as he was praying, heaven was opened and the Holy Spirit descended on him in bodily form like a dove. And a voice came from heaven: 'You are my Son, whom I love; with you I am well pleased'" (Luke 3:21-22 NIV).

Answer (score 2):

Rhetorician has given an excellent answer to your question.  There are many different views about the second coming of Christ but if I may, I would like to add a few points taken from the Bible.

The first coming of the Christ, the Messiah, happened some 2,000 years ago.  He was the humble servant king, prophesied in Isaiah chapter 53, who was oppressed and afflicted and led, like a lamb, to the slaughter.  He came to do the will of his Father in heaven:

> For he bore the sins of many, and made intercession for the transgressors (Isaiah 53:12).

***When he returns, it will not be as a humble servant king but as a judge.***  He will be accompanied by the heavenly hosts to destroy all God’s enemies, including the unseen agents of evil and darkness and all who follow them.  Yes, he will come with the clouds, and every eye will see him (Revelation 1:7) but the purpose of his second coming is to judge and make war:

> With justice he judges and makes war... The armies of heaven were following him... “He will rule them [the nations] with an iron sceptre.” (Revelation 19:11-16).

Christ Jesus is God’s anointed as Peter declared in his testimony of “Jesus Christ, who is Lord of all”:

> God anointed Jesus of Nazareth with the Holy Spirit and power, and how he went around doing good and healing all who were under the power of the devil, because God was with him...  he is the one whom God appointed as judge of the living and the dead” (Acts 10:38,42).

There are pretenders who seek to dethrone Him, false prophets and antichrists, but they will get their rewards at the second coming of our Lord and Saviour who is called Faithful and True, the Word of God, the KING OF KINGS AND LORD OF LORDS.  ***There is no other “anointed” by God.***

Comment: So you are saying that if God wanted to anoint someone else, even he isn't powerful enough to do so?

Comment: Absolutely, categorically, emphatically not. Before the incarnation God's plan of salvation had been set in motion - the Father sent the Son who came to earth to lay down his life and who was then resurrected and even now sits in heaven as God's anointed. Whe he returns it will be to execute judgment on all who have denied him, both the living and the dead. The sovereign and almighty God of creation has exerecised his power to provide the solution to sin and to death, namely his one, his only Son, Christ Jesus. Only God can do this. Only God has done this.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not up on my scripture but is the 'second coming of Christ', Jesus specifically?

I am answering from the Catholic and Protestant perspectives, however, I think that my answer is true for most other Christian denominations, too.

> ... or is it the coming of a yet another 'anointed one'?

No.

> ... so is the 'second coming' Jesus coming ...

Exactly this is meant.

The Apostles' Creed says about Jesus:

> ...
> He ascended into heaven, ...
> ...
> He will **come again** ...
> ...

This "coming again" is meant by "second coming of Christ".

> ... down from a cloud ...

I doubt that most Christians today think that "a cloud" will be involved...

Comment: Down from a cloud or 'out of thin air', he's not going to arrive on a plane.

You fundamentalists are just as bad as Athiiests.